# ¿Como puedo Cambiar el dato en un Grid?

Tags: c#, sap

Estoy desarrollando en DI API en SAP BO, el tema que estoy realizando un listado de los socios de negocio en un Grid, el cual me funciona bien excepto que el dato del tipo de socio de negocio me devuelve su valor en la base de datos y necesito que me muestre lo siguiente:
C = Cliente, S = Proveedor y L = Lead, pero no encuentro como recorrer el grid ya que la sintaxis de sap es algo diferente a lo que normalmente se usa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que uso para poder crear el grid y su llenado desde la base de datos

```
  private void cargarInfoGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            string cliente = "Cliente";
            string proveedor = "Proveedor";
            string lead = "Lead";

            SAPbouiCOM.Item oItem = null;
            SAPbouiCOM.Grid oGrid = null;

            myForm.DataSources.DataTables.Add("MyDataTable1");
            string query = "Select T0.CardCode, T0.CardName, T0.LicTradNum, T0.CardType From OCRD T0";
            myForm.DataSources.DataTables.Item("MyDataTable1").ExecuteQuery(query);

            //grid
            oItem = myForm.Items.Add("IGT_Grid", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_GRID);
            oItem.Left = 50;
            oItem.Top = 100;
            oItem.Width = 600;
            oItem.Height = 200;
            oGrid = (SAPbouiCOM.Grid)oItem.Specific;

            oGrid.DataTable = myForm.DataSources.DataTables.Item("MyDataTable1");
            oGrid.Columns.Item("CardCode").TitleObject.Caption = "Codigo";
            oGrid.Columns.Item("CardName").TitleObject.Caption = "Nombre";
            oGrid.Columns.Item("LicTradNum").TitleObject.Caption = "Rut";
            oGrid.Columns.Item("CardType").TitleObject.Caption = "Tipo de Socio de Negocio";

         
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetText("Error al cargar la informacion " + ex.Message, BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Error);
        }
    }
```

Solo necesito saber como podría cambiar los valores de esa columna para quedar terminar el Add-on que estoy desarrollando.

Answer (score 0):

Recorrer el grid y cambiar datos puede demorar mucho tiempo dependiendo de la cantidad de datos. Tienes esta alternativa:

En tu query traes como otra columna ya el `CardType` con el nombre que deseas mediante SQLServer (o lo equivalente en Hana) y el `CardType` lo traes pero ocultas la columna por si acaso lo requieras para otra cosa.

```
SELECT
    T0.CardCode, 
    T0.CardName, 
    T0.LicTradNum,  
    CASE WHEN T0.CardType = 'C' THEN 'Cliente' WHEN T0.CardType = 'S' THEN 'Proveedor' ELSE 'Lead' END,
    T0.CardType 
FROM OCRD T0
```